# Using JavaScript with GWT to get user location, but variable does not get passed

Tags: javascript, variables, geolocation

I have a simple code that uses javascript in a a java code (using google's GWT), so all I want to do is get the user's latitude and pass that number back to the Java code so I can do some computation on it.

However, I can't return the variable x= position.coords.latitude, back to my Java code because even though when I call alert(x), it displays the right latitude on my screen, when I try to return it, x is still null and nothing happens.

```
public static native Number findlatitude() /*-{
    var x;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            x = position.coords.latitude;
            alert(x);
        });
    }
    return x;
}-*/;
```

Comment: JavaScript in Java? o.O `Java-ception`

Comment: Have you tried setting the return type of your Function to String, does this still give null?

Comment: I tried changing return type to String and it still prints null :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the value of x from the function, you can assign the value of

```
position.coords.latitude
```

to a variable which can be accessed by the calling function. That way the assigned value to that variable will persist.
Some thing like this:
**EDIT**

```
var b;
function callingFunction(){
    findLocation();
    //your stuff
}
function floc(position){
    b = position.coords.longitude;
}
function findLocation(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(floc);
}

callingFunction();
```

Comment: Hey Digvijay Yadav, I tried your solution and it still returns null for some reason, I don't know why b doesn't get assigned to the new value in GWT

Comment: @noobiehacker: I have edited my answer. try it this way. It works for me.

Comment: Hey Digvijay Yadav thanks for the reply however, when i tried to add alert(b), after callingFunction(), I still cannot display the latitude and it still display null